# How to check whether a GeoCoordinates is along a route?

Tags: java, android, here-api

I have a route calculated by calling `RoutingEngine.calculateRoute()`. If I want to provide user with step by step instructions, I'd need a way to know whether the user is still en route, or if (s)he is off course (to calculate a new route). I have gone through the documentations but neither `com.here.sdk.mapviewlite.MapPolyline`, `com.here.sdk.routing.RouteLeg` or `com.here.sdk.routing.Route` have a method to check whether a given `GeoCoordinates` is *en route* or not. How do you achieve this?

Comment: Maybe they would have to be pretty far off already, but could you you check whether current location is in the boundingBox of any of the routeLegs? [if not, then they're off route]

Comment: @JeremyKahan That wouldn't be very accurate and not suitable for turn by turn instructions. Imagine (s)he misses a left turn in a dense urban environment, like Sydney

Comment: Point taken. I hope someone has a better idea. I started to think about distance from point to a polyline, but I wasn't sure what that would look like.

Comment: You can get Route.getRouteGeometry(), iterate through it and find closest distance from your position to the line between two "neighboring" geo position in the route geometry => i and i + 1, here's possible algorithm https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11409/calculating-the-distance-between-a-point-and-a-virtual-line-of-two-lat-lngs

Comment: @NazarK I cannot find `getRouteGeometry()`. Looks like _here_ removed it from Android SDK Lite

Comment: @NazarK Disregard my last comment. They have renamed it to `getShape()`

Answer (score 1):

Please refer : https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-sdk/dev_guide/topics/routing.html#get-map-matched-waypoints

The resulting route may, however, not exactly pass through the specified waypoint - for example, if the geographic coordinates point to a forest without streets or a lake. Route calculation will not necessarily fail, but the algorithm will attempt to come as close to the specified coordinates as possible